# Vim: paste multiple lines after multiple lines

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I paste multiple lines of code after every line of a visual block?

What I have is:

```
    foo
    bar

1
2
3
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
1
    foo
    bar
2
    foo
    bar
3
    foo
    bar
```

Is there a way to easily accomplish this?

Comment: you have your answers below, if it is something more complex than what you have shown then you should have a look at macros http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros

Comment: I was hoping that there was some way to do it using visual mode but I guess not. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: If you do want to use visual mode for this, something here might help: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Repeat_command_on_each_line_in_visual_block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cut it to the default register and do a global replacement for the rest of lines, like this:

Go to first column of first line of the file:

```
gg0
```

Cut data:

```
3dd
```

Do a global repeat for every line of the file and paste it:

```
:g/^/put
```

It yields:

```
1
    foo 
    bar 

2
    foo 
    bar 

3
    foo 
    bar
```

Comment: This one does it way better

Answer (score 2):

assume that you want to copy and paste line number `1 2 3`, run this command:

```
:g/^\S/1,3t.
```

then the text `foo bar` would be copied to right place. then you can remove the two lines.

You can also change the `1,3` to other range.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully automated but almost there:

- Visually highlight desired rows to copy with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Delete with <kbd>d</kbd>
- Move to first line ("`1`") and start recording with <kbd>q</kbd> followed by some letter, i.e., <kbd>a</kbd>.
- Paste with <kbd>p</kbd> and then move down to the next line ("`2`"). Stop recording with <kbd>q</kbd>.
- Now just repeat the last recorded command with <kbd>@@</kbd>, or + the designated letter, i.e., <kbd>@a</kbd>.